# Matplotlib: when plotting dict, not all values are plotted

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my keys and values in this nice barchart. However, some values are not plotted. In the image below you see for instance key '20' having value 120, however, in the chart key 20 has value 0. This happens for multiple keys, however, for most of them, the values plotted seem to be correct. How is this possible? And how can I solve this?

I work in iPynb, Python 3.5, matplotlib version 2.1.0.

[image: result]

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so you would want to extract it all at once, e.g. `x,y = zip(*dic.items()); plt.bar(x,y)`. Apart, please do not post just an image of the problem. Instead include a [mcve] of the issue in text form.

Comment: Also you can numbers as keys, just an fyi. They don't have to be strings.